# Point subdirectory to seperate website in IIS7 (hosted on same server)

Tags: domains, dns, iis7

I have 2 websites on the same server in IIS7.  These websites are required to be separate (Application Pools will not suffice).  I have a single domain and am not able to create subdomains.  Because of this I am only able to access Website A.  Can I point a subdirectory in Website A to Website B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Just create a new application with the desired sub path under the main site.  The new application can be run under a separate application pool.

Note that there may be fixes you need to make to the second application, because it is running with a sub path.  If it generates any absolute URLs or server-relative URLs, they must be generated with that in mind, or things may end up trying to go to the main application.

We always develop all our applications at a sub path and with a nonstandard port to make sure the code works in these scenarios.